# JS - replace quotation with apostrophe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a String like (the String represents another html elements):

```
<div id="myValue">Something</div>
```

which is a value of another field.

I Would like to add this value as an innerHTML to another div.

I need to replace the quotation `"` with apostrophe `'` from this string and then put it as innerHTML but how to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to convert to single quotes for adding as `innerHTML`?

Answer (score 0):

Use replace with a regex rule:

```
var content = document.getElementById("myValue")

content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML.replace(/\"/g, "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't. You would only need such a transformation if you were manually interpolating something in a template. In this case just let the DOM handle it:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.append').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    let rel = e.target.getAttribute('rel'),
      htmlContent = document.querySelector(`#${rel}`).value;
    console.log(htmlContent, rel);
    document.querySelector('#targetDiv').innerHTML += htmlContent;

  });
});
```

```css
.inputcontainer {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.htmlvalue {
  margin: 0.5em 0;
  width: 230px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.append {
  border-radius: 4px;
}


#targetDiv {
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
  min-height: 1em;
  min-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

#targetDiv>div {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 6px 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

#targetDiv .double {
  border: 2px dotted blue;
}

#targetDiv .single {
  border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputcontainer">
  <input class="htmlvalue " id="input1" value='<div class="double">Double Quoted</div>'>
  <button class="append" rel="input1">Append with " "</button>
</div>
<div class="inputcontainer">
  <input class="htmlvalue " id="input2" value="<div class='single'>Single Quoted</div>">
  <button class="append" rel="input2">Append with ' '</button>
</div>

<div id="targetDiv">

</div>
```